# Mongoimport Laradock

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Использую laradock, запускаю как 
sudo docker-compose up -d nginx mongo

Все запускается нормально, через Mongo Compass подключение работает

Далее хочу сделать импорт файла в коллекцию:
sudo docker-compose exec mongo mongoimport --db mydb --collection catalog --file /var/www/catalog2.json

В ответ мне пишет

> 2018-04-05T08:06:26.835+0000  Failed: open /var/www/catalog2.json: no such file or directory
>   2018-04-05T08:06:26.835+0000    imported 0 documents

Хотя файл по этому пути существует

### Update

Файл закинул в сам контейнер монги через
sudo docker-compose exec mongo bash

Далее делаю импорт и пишет

> 2018-04-05T08:38:12.504+0000  [........................] mydb.catalog 0B/3.59MB (0.0%)
>   2018-04-05T08:38:13.115+0000    [........................] mydb.catalog 0B/3.59MB (0.0%)
>   2018-04-05T08:38:13.115+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
>   2018-04-05T08:38:13.116+0000    imported 0 documents

Comment: Существует где? На хосте?

Comment: Да, если вы имеете ввиду workspace

Comment: Скорее всего он есть только снаружи контейнера, но внутри контейнера - у которого совсем отдельная файловая система - его нет, и его надо прокинуть как volume

Comment: обновил вопрос, проблема поменялась